# How to enable the Ethernet Interface on Pandaboard?

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, ethernet, pandaboard

As per my understanding, To achieve this goal I have to enable some kernel configuration of USB and Ethernet interface on Pandaboard. I am able to build the kernel and load the file system but I am not able to see any ethernet interface as an output to "ifconfig" command as well as nothing in the dmesg. I have set below kernel configurations to enable the interface but not able to enable the interface.

```
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_ROOT_HUB_TT=y
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED=y
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_OMAP=y
CONFIG_USB_USBNET=y
CONFIG_USB_NET_SMSC95XX=y
CONFIG_NETWORK_FILESYSTEMS=y
CONFIG_ROOT_NFS=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_BOOTP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_RARP=y
CONFIG_USB=y
CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_EHCI=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
```

Did I miss anything in configuration? I am using the kernel "4.16.0-rc1".

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to enable the ethernet interface. As per my understanding, on the Pandaboard ethernet is over USB interface. So in order to enable ethernet, I have to enable below few more kernel configuration apart from the configuration which I have mentioned in the question. With all this configuration I am able to enable the ethernet as well as USB interface on the board.

```
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_OMAP=y
CONFIG_USB_NET_LAN75XX=y
CONFIG_USB_STORAGE=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET=y
CONFIG_NOP_USB_XCEIV=y
```

Now the "`ifconfig`" command output also shows the ethernet interface.